# Pandas compare value with previous row with filtration condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, rows

I have a DataFrame with information about employee salary. It's about 900000+ rows.

Sample:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
|    |   table_num | name          |   salary |
|----+-------------+---------------+----------|
|  0 |      001234 | John Johnson  |     1200 |
|  1 |      001234 | John Johnson  |     1000 |
|  2 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1000 |
|  3 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1200 |
|  4 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1000 |
|  5 |      001235 | Steve Stevens |     1000 |
|  6 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |
|  7 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |
|  8 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

dtypes:

```
table_num: string
name: string
salary: float
```

I need to add a column with information about increased\decreased salary level.
I'm using the `shift()` function to compare value in rows.

Main problem is in filtration and iteration over all unique employees over the whole dataset.

**It takes about 3 and half hour** in my script.

**How to do it faster?**

My script:

```
# giving us only unique combination of 'table_num' and 'name'
    # since there can be same 'table_num' for different 'name'
    # and same names with different 'table_num' appears sometimes

names_df = df[['table_num', 'name']].drop_duplicates()

# then extracting particular name and table_num from Series
for i in range(len(names_df)):    ### Bottleneck of whole script ###    
    t = names_df.iloc[i,[0,1]][0]
    n = names_df.iloc[i,[0,1]][1]

    # using shift() and lambda to check if there difference between two rows 
    diff_sal = (df[(df['table_num']==t)
               & ((df['name']==n))]['salary'] - df[(df['table_num']==t)
                                                 & ((df['name']==n))]['salary'].shift(1)).apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else (-1 if x<0 else 0))
    df.loc[diff_sal.index, 'inc'] = diff_sal.values
```

Sample input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'table_num': ['001234','001234','001235','001235','001235','001235','001236','001236','001236'], 
                     'name': ['John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens'], 
                     'salary':[1200.,1000.,1000.,1200.,1000.,1000.,1200.,1200.,1200.]})
```

Sample output:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+-------+
|    |   table_num | name          |   salary |   inc |
|----+-------------+---------------+----------+-------|
|  0 |      001234 | John Johnson  |     1200 |     0 |
|  1 |      001234 | John Johnson  |     1000 |    -1 |
|  2 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1000 |     0 |
|  3 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1200 |     1 |
|  4 |      001235 | John Johnson  |     1000 |    -1 |
|  5 |      001235 | Steve Stevens |     1000 |     0 |
|  6 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |     0 |
|  7 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |     0 |
|  8 |      001236 | Steve Stevens |     1200 |     0 |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: So we only compare if they have same table_num and name right?

Comment: We can assume that the ordering is just based on the original df?

Comment: Combination of table_num and name is enough to define particular employee. Sorting matters. Original(BIG) df sorted by date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df['inc'] = df.groupby(['table_num', 'name'])['salary'].diff().fillna(0.0)
df.loc[df['inc'] > 0.0, 'inc'] = 1.0
df.loc[df['inc'] < 0.0, 'inc'] = -1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and last cast to `integer`s:

```
df['new'] = np.sign(df.groupby(['table_num', 'name'])['salary'].diff().fillna(0)).astype(int)
print (df)
   table_num           name  salary  new
0       1234   John Johnson    1200    0
1       1234   John Johnson    1000   -1
2       1235   John Johnson    1000    0
3       1235   John Johnson    1200    1
4       1235   John Johnson    1000   -1
5       1235  Steve Stevens    1000    0
6       1236  Steve Stevens    1200    0
7       1236  Steve Stevens    1200    0
8       1236  Steve Stevens    1200    0
```

Answer (score 1):

`shift()` is the way to go but you should avoid as much as you can to use loops. Here we can leverage the power of `groupby()` and `transform()`. Check the pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

In your case you can do it by writing:

```
df.assign(inc=lambda x: x.groupby(['name'])
                      .salary
                      .transform(lambda y: y - y.shift(1))
                      .apply(lambda x: 1 if x>0 else (-1 if x<0 else 0))
      )
```

yields:

```
    table_num   name       salary   inc
0   001234  John Johnson    1200.0  0
1   001234  John Johnson    1000.0  -1
2   001235  John Johnson    1000.0  0
3   001235  John Johnson    1200.0  1
4   001235  John Johnson    1000.0  -1
5   001235  Steve Stevens   1000.0  0
6   001236  Steve Stevens   1200.0  1
7   001236  Steve Stevens   1200.0  0
8   001236  Steve Stevens   1200.0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can search for terms: "pandas vectorization" to speed up operation with dataframe, for your question, could you try the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'table_num': ['001234','001234','001235','001235','001235','001235','001236','001236','001236'],
                     'name': ['John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson','John Johnson', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens', 'Steve Stevens'],
                     'salary':[1200.,1000.,1000.,1200.,1000.,1000.,1200.,1200.,1200.]})

df['temp'] = df['name'] + df['table_num']
df.sort_values('temp', inplace=True)
df['diff'] = df.groupby('temp')['salary'].diff()
df['diff'] = (df['diff'] / abs(df['diff'])).fillna(0)
```

Comment: applying a lambda will trash any hope of vectorization but I'm also getting a bit stuck on the last part :)

Comment: I am not really understand pandas :D and know someone will have better solution

Comment: Once you turn to lambda, you're going to start running in python time

Comment: Oh, thanks alot, didnt know that, I think i need to read more then

Comment: I was trying something like this but Im stuck at `df['temp'] = df['name'] + df['table_num']` cuz on frame size 900000+ rows process takes mutch time. And eats bunch of RAM. So I was out of RAM earlier than the process ended :)

Comment: :D yeah, shouldnt do that, just group by both, as answered

Comment: @phung-duy-phong I realized why is this happened. Some of the values was numeric. In this case `df['temp'] = df['name'].astype('str') + df['table_num'].astype('str')` do a trick in just few sec. Thanks for help again :)